# Responsive, cover-fit image tagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I have a slideshow with images as follows:

```
img {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

This makes the images fullscreen and behave like background-size:cover, so they fill out the whole viewport on any screen size without distortion.

I would like to tag certain points with text tooltips on these images. For this purpose I have found [Tim Severien's Taggd](https://timseverien.com/taggd/v3/), which works great on responsive images, but in my case the `object-fit:cover;` property makes the tagged positions inaccurate.

I have tried everything from CSS hacks to improving Tim's code, but I am out of ideas. If you have any solution or workaround in mind please share.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i actually wanted to do the same thing.
here is what i've done.
maybe it will help someone in the future.
it would be great if this feature could be integrated in taggd.

```
function buildTags()
{

    // be aware that image.clientWidth and image.clientHeight are available when image is loaded
    var croppedWidth = false;
    var expectedWidth = 0;
    var croppedWidthHalf = 0;
    var imageWidth = 0;
    var croppedHeight = false;
    var expectedHeight = 0;
    var croppedHeightHalf = 0;
    var imageHeight = 0;
    var naturalRatio = image.naturalWidth/image.naturalHeight;
    var coverRatio = image.clientWidth/image.clientHeight;
    if(Math.abs(naturalRatio - coverRatio) < 0.01)
    {
        // the image is not cropped, nothing to do
    }
    else
    {
        if(naturalRatio > coverRatio)
        {
            // width is cropped
            croppedWidth = true;
            expectedWidth = image.clientHeight * naturalRatio;
            croppedWidthHalf = (expectedWidth - image.clientWidth)/2;
            imageWidth = image.clientWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            // height is cropped
            croppedHeight = true;
            expectedHeight = image.clientWidth / naturalRatio;
            croppedHeightHalf = (expectedHeight - image.clientHeight)/2;
            imageHeight = image.clientHeight;

        }
    }
    function calcy(y)
    {
        if(croppedHeight)
        {
            var positiony = y * expectedHeight;
            if(positiony >  croppedHeightHalf)
                return (positiony - croppedHeightHalf)/imageHeight;
            else // tag is outside the picture because cropped
                return 0; // TODO : handle that case nicely
        }
        else
            return y;
    }

    function calcx(x)
    {
        if(croppedWidth)
        {
            var positionx = x * expectedWidth;
            if(positionx > croppedWidthHalf)
                return (positionx - croppedWidthHalf)/imageWidth;
            else // tag is outside the picture because cropped
                return 0; // TODO : handle that case nicely
        }
        else
            return x;
    }

    var tags = [

      Taggd.Tag.createFromObject({
        position: { x: calcx(0.74), y: calcy(0.56) },
        text: 'some tag',
      }),
      Taggd.Tag.createFromObject({
        position: { x: calcx(0.9), y: calcy(0.29) },
        text: 'some other tag',
      }),

      ....
    ];
    var taggd = new Taggd(image, options, tags);

}
$(window).bind("load", function() {buildTags();});
```

Answer (score -1):

Is not possible. Think if the user has a tablet with 1024x768 resolution, when the user change view from horizontal to vertical the image can fill the space but you will loose part of the image, loose img quality, etc. 
The best way for cross devices is to use big pictures and add in css

```
img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

And fill image background with a color;